# React JS Router error: Some components aren't beign rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

The following code has some sort of error in the router
App.js

```
import Home from './pages/Home.js'
import Invites from './pages/Invites.js'
import {createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
  Route,
  Link,
  RouterProvider,
  MemoryRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import './App.css';

const Root = () =>{
  return(
    <>
      <h1>Is it working?</h1>
    </>
  )
}

function App() {
  const router = createBrowserRouter(createRoutesFromElements(
      <Route path="/" element={<Root />} >
        <Route index element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/invt" element={<Invites />} />
      </Route>
    )
  )
  return (
    <>
      <RouterProvider router={router}/>
      <div className="App">
        <MemoryRouter>
          <Link to="invt">Invitations</Link>
        </MemoryRouter>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The `<Root>` and the content of the tag `<div className="App">` renders, but the `<Home>` doesn't.
When I click on the 'Invitations' link, nothing happens.
When I manually navigate to "localhost:3000/invt" the `<Invites>` doesn't renders either.
`Home` and `Invites` are minimal pages made solely to test the router by now.

I expected the `<Root>` to be rendered all the time, the `<Home>` to be rendered at "localhost:3000" and the `<Invites>` to be rendered at "localhost:3000/invt".
Also expected to enter the "localhost:3000/invt" when I clicked the text between `<Link to="invt">`.
None of this happened.

PS:
I am using react-router-dom 6.10
Must be important, since every tutorial I try to follow is very distinct from previous ones and leads to some new weird error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Root` component necessarily should render an `Outlet` component for the nested routes to render their `element` content into.

The link should also be rendered within the same router/routing context it is linking to.

Example:

```
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
  Route,
  Link,
  RouterProvider,
  Outlet
} from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './pages/Home.js'
import Invites from './pages/Invites.js'
import './App.css';

const Root = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Is it working?</h1>
      <Outlet />
      <div className="App">
        <Link to="invt">Invitations</Link>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

function App() {
  const router = createBrowserRouter(
    createRoutesFromElements(
      <Route path="/" element={<Root />} >
        <Route index element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/invt" element={<Invites />} />
      </Route>
    )
  );

  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

export default App;
```